# many packages not available in the updated R

Tags: r

I'm running an RNAseq analysis in R. I'm using the DESeq2 package, which also requires "apeglm". I tried to install "apeglm" but it gave an error that this package is not available for the version of R I'm using. So I updated my R version, but now I run to the same error for installing DESeq2 on R 4.1.2. I would appreciate any clue.

Comment: Cod you post ythe error in full please

Comment: It's difficult to help with your problem without more information, as rg255 already said. Since `apeglm` is a Bioconductor package, please be sure that you have `"BiocManager"` successfully installed before you try to install, and then show the full output from `BiocManager::install("apeglm")`. (If you tried to do `install.packages("apeglm")`, then it's no surprise it fails as that package is not on CRAN.)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure what the problem was, but BiocManager::install("apeglem") worked.